# Word for liking and not liking something at the same time?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What's a word for the feeling of liking something, but not liking it at the same time? I love the way the Spanish speak, but it bothers me at the same time. I've looked through and dictionaries asked teachers, but i can't seem to find the right word. I would really appreciate the help, thank you.

Comment: You have a love-hate relationship with Spanish.

Comment: You are ambivalent about it.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod This should be made an answer.

Answer (score 4):

*Ambivalent* is appropriate.

> **adjective**
>
> having mixed feelings about someone or something; being unable to choose between two (usually opposing) courses of action: *The whole family was ambivalent about the move to the suburbs.* ([dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ambivalent))