# Word for someone who wants an action to be taken and not taken at the same time?

Tags: single-word-requests

This is not a hypocrite. That's someone who says not to do a thing and does it themself.

I want a word for someone who both wants a thing to happen and to not happen at the same time.

For example, my dog wants to play tug of war but if you do, she's mad about it. But if you don't, she's also mad about it because no one is playing with her. So she both wants to play and doesn't want to play at the same time.

This is not a duplicate of the [liking and not liking something at the same time question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227878/word-for-liking-and-not-liking-something-at-the-same-time) because liking and wanting are two different (yet related) things. Also, this is more specific to an actual action. Liking something and it bothering you is not the same as actively wanting to do a thing and actively not wanting to do a thing at the same time.

Comment: They "can't be satisfied".

Comment: Schrödinger's cat?

Comment: Conflicted. Of two minds. Torn. On the fence. I could go either way.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence "my dog wants to play tug of war but if you do, she's mad about it". It doesn't make sense to me. Why is the dog mad about it?

Comment: @TimR that's an extremely rude thing to say whether you're joking or not. You've been reported

Comment: Yes, I was joking.